Build a music licensing system using metaplex
hey I am new to solana and blockchain in general. I was hoping to build a project and learn alongside. My idea is to build a music streaming/licensing platform where users can buy rights for usage purposes and stream music too. My planned architecture was to just build a next app ( without a special smart contract ) . I came across metaplex and there's just too many options (metaplex core, candymachine v3, sugar, CM core) and I know they might enable different usecases but im just too new to figure out what to stick with to satisfy my usecase. I want to enable musicians to come on the platform, make an album (an NFT collection) and tracks in it (tokens) and users on the internet should be able to buy off a track from an album. How should i go about it?
